# While loop not working in the series data highcharts - php

Tags: php, highcharts

This is my Table structure
[image]
[image]

```
  Here is my code: <br/>
  <?php 
     $result_journ = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal FROM journals");                                                             
    $count_result = mysql_num_rows($result_journ);                                                


  while ($row_sd = mysql_fetch_array($result_journ)) {
   $data_sd = $row_sd['jour_id'];
   $namee= $row_sd['journal'];
  ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#container_journal').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php
    $test_q = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, year FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '$data_sd'");
    while($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($test_q)){
        $year_q = $row_q['year']; 
        echo $year_q.',';
    }?>
       ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Citations'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: '<?php echo $namee; ?>',
            data: [<?php
    $sql= "SELECT `citations`, `jour_id` FROM `journ_graph` WHERE `jour_id` = '$data_sd'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $cita = $row['citations'].',';
    ?>]
        }]
    });
});

</script>

   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

**The Result:**
[image]
This is the result I am getting.

**The expected Result:**
[image]

The while loop is getting only one row. What would be the problem? Please help.
The while loop is getting only one row. What would be the problem? Please help.

**Update Result**:
[image]

**Checkbox select**
[image]

Comment: You are reinitializing the highcharts on each iteration of first while

Comment: How to solve this bro. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinitializing the highcharts on each iteration of first while. Try the following code:

```
<?php
$result_journ = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, journal FROM journals");
$count_result = mysql_num_rows($result_journ);
$categories = "";
$cita = array();
$count=0;
while ($row_sd = mysql_fetch_array($result_journ))
{
    $data_sd = $row_sd['jour_id'];
    $cita[$count]['name'] = $row_sd['journal'];

    $test_q = mysql_query("SELECT jour_id, year FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '$data_sd'");

    while ($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($test_q))
    {
        $year_q = $row_q['year'];
        $categories .= $year_q . ',';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `citations`, `jour_id` FROM `journ_graph` WHERE `jour_id` = '$data_sd'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // I have added this while block thinking that you might have more than one rows
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {            
        $cita[$count]['data'][] = $row['citations'];
    }
    $count++;

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#container_journal').highcharts({

            xAxis: {
                categories: [<?= $categories ?>]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: 'Citations'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: <?= json_encode($cita, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: See if the `categories` and `data` are populated

Comment: print the value of `$categories` and `$cita` and post what you get

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38755/discussion-between-razor-and-deepak)

Comment: Bro I found the problem, it is not getting the id I mean $data_sd?

Comment: print_r($cita) and post the results after the while loop

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => A + U-Architecture and Urbanism [data] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 54 [2] => 23 [3] => 43 ) ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => A + U-Architecture and Urbanism [data] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 54 [2] => 23 [3] => 43 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => AACE International. Transactions of the Annual Meeting [data] => Array ( [0] => 45 [1] => 34 [2] => 32 [3] => 35 ) ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => A + U-Architecture and Urbanism [data] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 54 [2] => 23 [3] => 43 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => AACE International. Transactions of the

Comment: Like this is going on printing for half page.

Comment: Bro you are awesome, one more doubt bro please wait.

Comment: Now check the update of my question. If I have a checkbox at the left for each row, if user selects any checkbox the graph must show according to the checkbox.

Comment: You need to post that as a new question to get better responses. :)

Comment: Highcharts by default will allow you to do it. If you click on the labels it will get activated and deactivated.

Comment: Yes there is someway or the other you can make that happen.. I could think of ajaxy way

Comment: This is completely different topic from your original question. And I cant answer you here if you are extending the topic which is against SO. I suggest you to post this as a new question..